# Make form active

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I have application that currently not active. On timer event I need to show this application selection form (yes/no) to user. This form must have keyboard input focus.

What function I must use to make currently not active application form active?  `SetWindowPos`, `SetFocus` does't help.  `SetWindowPos` - shows form, but is still has no focus.

Probably first of all I need to make whole application active?

When form is shown to user and user has done selection how to bring focus back to application that had it before timer event?

Application is created using `MFC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answere to your first question is yes, you have to make your whole application active.
To put your window at the top level with input focus you can use BringWindowToTop. 
To know wich is the current top window you can call GetTopWindow with NULL.

Comment: And how to make my application active?

Comment: SetForegroundWindow does it